# Is geolocation really supported in Spotify apps ? I get an error

Tags: geolocation, spotify

```
if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(callback);
}
```

I get this error : Uncaught Error: TYPE_MISMATCH_ERR: DOM Exception 17

Answer (score 0):

The API is there, but you'll get a `PERMISSION_DENIED` error in all cases at the moment. The error you're getting seems odd, though - does that code work in Chrome?

Comment: Getting "User denied Geolocation" inside of spotify app I'm developing. But I never got a prompt so how did I deny?

Comment: You didn't - the Spotify client doesn't allow it, which is why you get `PERMISSION_DENIED` in all cases.